# GPS receiver component power consumption

Tags: power

I am currently stuck on an assignment where I must state what main parts of a in-car GPS receiver (in this case, the signal amplifier and the screen are what I am concerned with) consume the largest percentage of the power supplied to the GPS receiver. I have stated the parts, now I must state actual power consumption figures (in mW, preferably) that are typical to these components. I have spend hours researching these figures, but have not been able to find anything I can use. The power values can be of any GPS receiver, I just need the numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the receiver itself, or are you talking about a complete navigation unit (antenna, integrated GPS receiver, LCD display with backlight, general purpose processor to drive display and handle user interaction, etc.)  Information on a just the receiver is easy to find, I found several in a couple of minutes on Google.  Information on the components of a complete navigation unit would be hard to come by - that would depend on the model in question and there's no guarantee the manufacturers provide that info.

Comment: "figures that are typical" - If you can't find those, you may have to come up with your own survey of what's "typical". Gather some datasheets and aggregate the different numbers suitably.

Comment: Pick an example part for all the components, figure out their power requirements, and start from there.

Comment: Try to modify the question to reflect what approach you've taken with the research you've done.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this, you have to dig around in some datasheets.  Go to a site like Mouser and look for GPS receiver chips or chip sets, and some graphics screens.  The datasheets should tell you the power consumption.  This will likely vary quite a bit between screens, probably less so for GPS receivers.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "signal amplifier".  Certainly there will be some amplification stages in the RF and demodulated signal paths in the GPS receivers, but you're not going to find power consumption of those broken out separately.  It seems strange that you want this anyway.  GPS reception is nowadays done with chips or chip sets for that purpose, and you don't have access to individual internal blocks like that.  In any case, the power consumption for the whole GPS receiver gives you a upper bound on any part within.

I haven't looked at any such datasheets, but I'd be really surprised if the display screen isn't the dominating power consumer by a considerable margin.  With the backlight, this is a no-brainer.  You can pretty much take the backlight power and figure that will be well over half the power of a whole GPS receiver with screen.  The actual RF reception doesn't take that much power.  The digital processing to do the math to compute the lat/lon and altitude from the time offsets is probably the dominant power consumer in a GPS receiver.

Another back door way to get a upper bound on GPS reception and processing power is to get the datasheet of a small hand-held unit.  This will usually tell you how long the batteries will last, hopefully with the screen off and on.  The energy in the batteries divided by that time will give you power drawn.  The basic GPS receiver won't be all that different from the hand-held unit to the car.  The main difference is that the car unit will have a much larger, brighter, and power hungrier screen.